# Why does Ubuntu not lock ATA-Password protected disc on reboot?

Tags: 13.04, boot, grub2, hard-drive

I am on a Acer Timeline X 4830TG Laptop. Currently using Ubuntu 13.04.
I do use 2 HDDs instead of the DVD-ROM drive.

I can set ATA passwords within bios for both drives (which I have done).
If I cold-start the machine I am forced by Bios to enter the HDD Passwords (at least I must unlock the one which is marked as bootable).

Than GRUB starts and I can boot into Ubuntu.

If I did not unlock the second Harddisk I will get many log lines about /dev/sdb not be accessible. 
(see kernel.log here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6179903/ )

[also not this second HardDrive is not mounted via fstab nor are there any requird partitions for ubuntu, it is instead a NTFS Volume which I manually mount if I need to acess this data-grave]

But anyway: the main problem and question is: 
why the heck does Ubuntu not lock the 1.HDD if i reboot it 
 ./.
why does it only lock the 2.Harddrive if it was unlocked before reboot?

The Result is this: I reboot Ubuntu, 2. HDD gets locked, first stays unlocked, Bios WON't ask for HDD Password (of the second, locked HDD) so I end up with above linked errors on bootup and also am unable to acess the second HDD from within Ubuntu, cause it is locked.

My expected behaviour would be either: both drives get locked during reboot, or
NONE of them gets locked, so the state AFTER reboot will be like it was before.

Thanks for answers in  advance.

Comment: This seems to be BIOS problem, not Ubuntu... Try to upgrade your bios.

Comment: the Bios is already up to date, why shuld this be relevant to the bios? isn't the OS in charge of relocking the HDD?

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is incorrect; it isn't the job of the OS to do this.  Instead the drive locks itself when you power off.

You may be able to manually unlock the drive in Ubuntu using the `hdparm --security-unlock` command, assuming the bios doesn't freeze the security settings, in which case it takes a power cycle to unfreeze it.